# Why can't I use string interpolation in an attribute?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I'm writing unit tests (MSTest) in C# 6.0 and I noticed something strange in the way the compiler handles string interpolation in attributes.

Why does this work:

```
[TestCategory(nameof(MyClass) + "-UnitTest")]
```

When this doesn't?

```
[TestCategory($"{nameof(MyClass)}-UnitTest")]
```

Ignoring the fact that this might not be a great way to categorize my tests; I'm curious why the compiler allows one and not the other.

Comment: Does `string.Format("{0}-UnitTest", nameof(MyClass))` work?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2077

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the compiler encounters an interpolated string it immediately converts it into a call to [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) so...

```
[TestCategory($"{nameof(MyClass)}-UnitTest")]
```

Becomes...

```
[TestCategory(string.Format("{0}-UnitTest", nameof(MyClass)))]
```

[*Attributes require that their arguments be constant expressions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10445772/5147646) but the above expression will not be evaluated until execution time hence the error...

> [CS0182](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ze6t76(v=vs.90).aspx) An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type...

*You* know all the information *is* available at compile time but the compiler is not smart enough to figure it out.

`nameof` works a bit differently than interpolated strings because it is [*evaluated at compile-time*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573102/is-nameof-evaluated-at-compile-time) so there is no error.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this to be able to use nameof in Attribute?

Answer (score 6):

Interpolated strings are not constant values.  The value is determined at runtime, even though in your case all inputs can be calculated at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

An attribute argument has to be a compile-time constant. While `nameof()` is a constant (see [Is nameof() evaluated at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573102/is-nameof-evaluated-at-compile-time)), the string interpolation feature itself is not.

> An interpolated string expression creates a string by replacing the contained expressions with the ToString represenations of the expressions’ results.

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation happens in [runtime](http://nblumhardt.com/2015/01/c-6-string-interpolation-and-serilog/) and attributes are present in [compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311719/is-net-attribute-feature-used-at-compile-time-or-run-time-or-both).
So your compiler cant resolve this, as it would be compiled like so:

```
[TestCategory(new FormattableString
  {
    Format = "{0}-UnitTest",
    Args = new object[] { nameof(MyClass)}
  })]
```